# Scala error function deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: scala, haskell

I am porting some Haskell code over into Scala. In Haskell I can use the *error* function. It seems at some point you could do this in Scala but the IDE is showing me that this is deprecated now. Here is the code:

```
def prime (n : Int) : Boolean = () match {
    case _ if n < 1 => error("not a positive integer")
    case _ if n == 1 => false
    case _ => ld (n) == n
}
```

What do I use instead of the error function in Scala now?

Comment: As a note, you really ought to avoid `error` in Haskell for something a little bit nicer and less "completely crash the program"-y

Comment: These are small throw away programs I am writing and porting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `sys.error` as [mentioned](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L141) in `deprecated` message.

```
@deprecated("Use `sys.error(message)` instead", "2.9.0")
```

You could run scala with `-deprecation` option to get this message:

```
scala> def t = error("t")
<console>:7: warning: method error in object Predef is deprecated: Use `sys.error(message)` instead
```