# Scala Cannot Resolve Symbol Exit

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
def nextOption(map : OptionMap, list: List[String]) : OptionMap = {
      def isSwitch(s : String) = (s(0) == '-')
      list match {
        case Nil => map
        case "--inputFile" :: value :: tail =>
          nextOption(map ++ Map('input -> value.toString), tail)
        case "--schemaFile" :: value :: tail =>
          nextOption(map ++ Map('schema -> value.toString), tail)
        case "--outputD" :: value :: tail =>
          nextOption(map ++ Map('output -> value.toString), tail)
        case "--delimiter" :: value :: tail =>
          nextOption(map ++ Map('delimiter -> value.toString), tail)
        case option :: tail => println("Unknown option "+option)
            exit(1)
      }
    }
```

The only issue is I get "Cannot Resolve Symbol Exit" in intellij. I picked this code from a popular post about accepting input parameters and it doesnt look like anyone else is getting this issue.

Answer (score 4):

`exit` used to be defined in `Predef`, meaning that it was always in scope. It is now defined in package `scala.sys`, so just do `sys.exit(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

It was [deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L144) in `2.9` and replaced with `sys.exit`.

Related question: [Scala error function deprecated. What is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21890567/406435)